# About x86 Prefetch instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

How many bytes does PREFETCH instruction bring into cache??? Is it equal to the cache line size? Is it possible to prefetch data whose length is greater than the cache line size?

Comment: "The implementation of prefetch locality hints is implementation-dependent, and can be overloaded or ignored by a 
processor implementation. The amount of data prefetched is also processor implementation-dependent. It will, 
however, be a minimum of 32 bytes." [Vol. 2B 4-277](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/253667.pdf)